# How to avoid NaNs in applymap()?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do a simple operation, converting a dataframe to titlecase.

There are some NaNs which cause errors, so I'd like to avoid them by applying `str.title()` only if it's `not null`.

However I'm getting `invalid syntax`.

```
df= df.applymap(lambda x: x.title() if pd.notnull(x))
                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Another try:

```
df= df.applymap(lambda x: x.title() if not pd.isnull(x))

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Why would the presence of NaN cause errors? I thought str.title() would just ignore them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is a [`conditional expression`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) you have to also provide a value for the `else` (if the condition is not met).

try this:

```py
df= df.applymap(lambda x: x.title() if pd.notnull(x) else '')
```

Comment: Thanks. Does an if statement always need an `else`?

Comment: @SCool no, but is not a real if statement, it is an expression that must evaluate to some value.

Answer (score 3):

#### `pandas.Series.str.title`

```
df.stack().str.title().unstack()
```

---

#### `numpy.core.defchararray.title`

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import title

title(df.to_numpy().astype(str))
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, which one is faster :(1) reshape matrix into a single column to apply str methods, vs (2)`apply` str methods on each column of a matrix

Answer (score 2):

You could fill the missing values with a blank string:

```
df = df.fillna("").applymap(lambda x: x.title())
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be faster to run `Series.str.title`

```
df.apply(lambda x:x.str.title())
```